# UIView detaches from bottom of UICollectionView on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that allows a user to enter reps via a UIView containing a picker. The picker container attaches to the bottom of the view as long as the UICollectionView doesn't need to scroll. As more cells are added and the view must scroll, my picker container no longer attaches to the bottom of my view. I have attached a screenshot of my issue and code showing how I have attached my pickerContainer to the bottom of my collectionView.

```
let pickerContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.collectionView.frame.height - pickerContainerHeight, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: pickerContainerHeight))
<....some other code that i dont think matters....>
collectionView.addSubview(pickerContainer)
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using constraints for UI in the storyboard builder I suggest that you add a view(containing the picker view and outlets attached in the view controller) there with proper constraint attached to the bottom of the super view and whenever the picker view is needed to be presented or dismissed then show/hide that view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t add it to the collection view as it will be added to scrollable area.

You can add it to the superview of collection view and put it above collection if you using storyboard. Or move in front using `pickerContainer.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(view: pickerContainer)` in case you interested in only in programmatically version.